# How to read content of a file from FTP server without downloading into local folder in command prompt?

Tags: vbscript, ftp

Using below code , i  can download the required file from FTP server.

```
script = script & "lcd " & """" & localDir & """" & vbCRLF
script = script & "open " & hostname & " " & port & vbCRLF
script = script & "user " & username & vbCRLF
script = script & password & vbCRLF
script = script & "cd " & """" & remoteDir & """" & vbCRLF
script = script & "binary" & vbCRLF
script = script & "prompt n" & vbCRLF
script = script & "mget " & """" & remoteFile & """" & vbCRLF
script = script & "quit" & vbCRLF

shell.Run "%comspec% /c FTP -n -s:" & scriptFile & " > " & outputFile, 0, TRUE
```

Requirements:

1. Instead of downloading every file, I just want to open the file, read the content, and confirm that file contains the requested text.
2. Is there any way to rename a file before downloading into local folder using FTP?

Comment: 1. If you're opening and reading a file on a remote server, you're already _downloading_ that information. You just don't want to create a disk file on the local machine?

Answer (score 0):

> *1. Instead of downloading every file, I just want to open the file, read the content, and confirm that file contains the requested text.*

No. You cannot check the contents of the file without downloading the contents (i.e. the file) first. If you want to do that you need something that allows you to run validation code on the remote side (e.g. SSH).

> *2. Is there any way to rename a file before downloading into local folder using FTP?*

Yes. You could use the [`rename`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490677.aspx) command. However, you need to rename each file individually, so you need to retrieve the directory listing first, and use it to build a second script for renaming the remote files.

Comment: Thank you, for sharing valuable information with me.